# Embed fonts under Apache 2 license in PDF - is that allowed?

Tags: pdf, fonts, licensing

I would like to embed Droid fonts in PDF documents generated by the application (invoices sent to customers).
Those fonts are distributed under the Apache License 2.0.

Is it legal to do that? Do I need to specify the font copyright in the document?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a lawyer, but... yes: as I read and understand the Apache 2 license, it would allow you to embed the Droid font into PDF documents.

Also, you do not need to specify the font copyright in the document separately in a human-readable form -- a short version of this license will be part of the fontfile (full set or subset) embedded in the PDF anyway.